# Using Github API to retrieve list commit SHAs

Tags: java, httprequest, github-api

I'm trying to use Github APIs to get a list of the SHAs corresponding to each commit on a given repository.
I've tried using this API:
`https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits`
And this return a list of commit object each of them containg its SHA.
The problem is that I perform this API request through a java program but the response always gets empty body and 200 as status code.
The program I'm using is this:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;

public class IntermediateStructureMaker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create client
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

        // create request
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest
                .newBuilder().uri(URI.create("https://api.github.com/repos/jithin-renji/Nuke/commits"))
                .build();

        // use the client to send the request
        client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString())
                .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                .thenAccept(System.out::println)
                .join();

    }

}
```

If I set the parameter `?per_page=1` in the request, I get the expected response; so I guess it's a problem of size of the response.
As solution I thought to only ask the SHA of the commits through the API request, is it possible?

Comment: your program works for me, it prints an array of 29 "commits object"

Comment: Okay, I tried running the program from CLI and it actually works. Probably Eclipse console has some kind of limit. Thank you for the answer!